# Using headless chrome number format is messed up

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I am using headless chrome. Most of the test cases do pass with this change. 
But wherever any number assertions are there, they are failing, which is nearly 100 tests out of 800 tests.

Ex: 
The following asserts failed: Incorrect promotion percentage Expected: "15%" but: was "0.150000000000000" Amount is incorrect Expected: "-1000.00 USD" but: was "-1000.000000000000000 USD"

Is there any central place where I can change the setting and these number formatting issue can be resolved. Or should I update each test case. Using java 8, selenium web driver, chromedriver 2.40

Comment: please show an example.  At the very minimum, show the EXACT code in one of your failing asserts... it's useless for people to make guesses about what you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem. I resolved this by setting the locale through command line option for headless chrome browser as follows. It looks like in headless mode, chrome browser hasn't been set with any locale but these formatters have a dependency over locale. Hence the problem. I passed the locale to chrome options

chrome.switches=--headless,--window-size=1920,1080,**--lang=en**